# How to preserve the type in generic class method with Zod schema?

Tags: typescript, validation, axios, zod

I am trying to create a validating fetch client with Axios and Zod. This is my current code

```js
export class ValidatedAxiosClient {
  delete = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('delete');
  get = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('get');
  patch = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('patch');
  put = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('put');
  post = this.createValidatedAxiosRequest('post');

  constructor(private clientName: string, private baseUrl: string) {}

  private createValidatedAxiosRequest(method: HTTPMethod) {
    return async <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
      url: string,
      responseSchema: T,
      config?: AxiosRequestConfig
    ): Promise<T | never> => {
      try {
        const response = await axios({ ...config, method, url, baseURL: this.baseUrl });

        return responseSchema.parse(response.data);
      } catch (error: any) {
        if (error.constructor.name === 'ZodError') {
          // Handle Zod error
          console.log("Zod error")
        } else {
          // Handle other errors
          console.log("Other error")
        }
        // This is here for now to satisfy the "| never" part from the return type
        throw error
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Now if I try to use that

```js
const User = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number()
});

type User = z.infer<typeof User>;

const UserClient = new ValidatedAxiosClient("User client", "http://localhost:3001")

const { name, age } = await UserClient.get("/user", User, { params: { id: "123" } } )
```

I get the error at destructuring saying

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type

'ZodObject<
 {
   name: ZodString;
   age: ZodNumber; 
 }, 
 "strip",
 ZodTypeAny,
 {
   name: string;
   age: number;
 },
 {
   name: string;
   age: number;
 }>'
 
 .ts(2339)
```

Then if I use the type for the function, TS shows that the destructuring correctly, but I then get error complaining about the type `User` itself

```js
const { name, age } = await UserClient.get<User>("/user", User, { params: { id: "123" } } )
```

```
Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'ZodType<any, any, any>'.

Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ZodType<any, any, any>': _type, _output, _input, _def, and 31 more.ts(2344)
```

Is there a way to create this kind of wrapper class so that the type safety is guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the type that is the output of a zod schema, you must use the `z.infer` type.

Which makes your return type this:

```
Promise<z.infer<T>>
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFCiSxwCGAHsBAM4A0icAgg8wEoCmARwCufJjADCEAHaZgAc3RYcefPUZNyZPnSrwAxgBsaTJnABqNA8GI0YfYl3XirfKfARk4cYnwN87cAC8cDAAFsBMAHR6UHy2fBZWNnYO3Ez8wqIwABT4Pn52+ACUANyecHL+QSHhUTFxdonW8anqGSJiuZUwxWVeYLZ6odVhEdGx8U3J9o68gh05+AMwQ73lYELwwaN1E42WzSmz6fNZuRs9pevMWzVj9ZMH061zmZ1LN2vletJiUEJ6GDQbJgKDAABu8TghmArhgADkaCA+AAuOB-YBSORsUEQqEAI2MfAAqlADGiMViiog0GR1mDIQEHvski1ju0zsiwiQKTAwVTEOUvLEYEIoFJaEwAJ5SPRwAA8ABU4No7FJiKZkJEAFokRVSsB8DhSKUAPmyQq8cDF5PRfMx2MtwtEkCkTD4AGUhnwQDQ0YqWE7odJZHIAPxo9mnMSSGTyS1FNEABWUET48q1mMwfCgStNpqCBY8VqtfKlgpLJZ+bvgsSYrvd1RoAHcaMB4GpmNkkJFe9XQ2wuaESGwbWxCe7iTwADJonaRCcksnoK5B52i8VwOsNz3e32RAZQd3Zbe-PiRZI0K6VxR6QbDbI5nBQNE0E3U4s3uDATBwR9QZ9ol+PkASBKBIikJE+CCQJgnwXViAAUQA6BigrL8vAAekwuAAAk32IPw4AQlUUKgNcrWrJgID8SIDAgORsgAIhIp9oCYooKIwXxG0-DDsLwgiiIgMIc1I58mAorwqJo896MYpiAHlRKgcT2M4jDaX4nDFVqb9TFCHNoMwaA4CkCBmxCCB0VsCJMHLUS4CYgAfMy+HBHMmLgQ94GwXAamgkUxQlGADT4CiwhwSy2PIm8tKtNA+nQMhaTIKj4GJd1VOCLUIHxAArPhAW7cpIORNEtUpRiikDLwaEqCqIKEEB8RzbJOLQVdQsNOBMrEnLIizHN5W6vgIF-PqoFNMo0uA3qsucWE3GqKQ+EsqY2TSRa4WYyboRcNwmLYJjQhgGAwBRbD6LvAxhzEFEAGYAAYnoARg4ul0vYMq+DYeroIwYIWzbDKFoOmBIm6ZjMKELKjvmnM2CQQ8kSYNEkGsNEmNegAmB6vIwDBqQE2RVrIIA)

---

Additionally `T | never` is identicaly in every way to just `T`. `never` is the absence of all type information. So when included in a union it just disappears.

And when a function throws, TypeScript knows that it should not try to satisfy the return type of that function.

Comment: Hmmm okay. That's interesting. I thought that the T is already the inferred type, because it is given as the extended type generic

Comment: Well you pass a schema to `responseSchema: T`, which is the object that has the parse method. So `z.infer<T>` would be the type returned by that objects `parse` method.